# How to write webapi methods inside Angular2 application

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular2-routing

I have angular2 project in visual studio.

[image]

I have written HTTPGet And HttpPost methods into their controllers as :-

[image]

When I try to access these methods through browser :-

http://localhost:54108/values/GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult

It shows me page not found error :-

[image]

How can I access these method as web api?

Comment: Have you tried using http://localhost:54108/api/values/GetAmbiguityAnalysisResult

Comment: yes..same page not found

Comment: Make sure your API is up and running and after that try studying how routing is done in Web API, that will help you. Refer below link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api